# Docker upgrade issue cent os 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, docker

I am trying to upgrade docker on my Cent Os 6.5 virtual machine but facing some problem .

when i try to start docker service it didnt start and its status is stopped.

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo service docker status
docker is stopped
```

I tried installing docker using below command

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo yum install docker
```

it exited with following error

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/docker from install of docker-1.5-5.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package docker-io-1.5.0-1.el6.x86_64
```

and with docker-io command

```
[root@localhost /]# sudo yum install docker-io
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
 * epel: mirrors.vinahost.vn
 * extras: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
 * updates: centosmirror.go4hosting.in
Package docker-io-1.5.0-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

so this is my current situation and i just want to remove current docker version and install docker 1.6 .

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think docker 1.6.0 is officially released for CentOS. You can try building it manually from git source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need upgrade the kernel to version >= 3.19. Then you can install docker v1.6.2 from repository:
http://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora-epel/6/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

The package is called `docker-io` on CentOS 6.5 (you can see why here: https://docs.docker.com/installation/rhel/).

However, EPEL currently only has Docker 1.5, so you can't upgrade to Docker 1.6 from there: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/docker-io.html

You can check for updates on the status of the package here: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/docker-io